# Some databases not getting backed up through the job

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-administration

I am getting this weird problem with my backup job.
I have more than 1000 DB's on my SQL server stack. There is a weekly and daily backup jobs set to take the backup. Weekly jobs runs on every sunday and does the full backup and then the daily job does the differential backup.

Now I realized that the last Full backup of some of the databases is not updated.
I checked the job history and the job was successful without any error. When I check in the backup folder, the timing of the backup seems a bit doubtful e.g

```
    26/10/2014  23:34     2,759,240,192 DB1 2014-10-26 23.19.59 Full.bak    
    26/10/2014  23:36       319,891,968 DB2 2014-10-26 23.34.46 Full.bak    
    26/10/2014  23:36       160,771,072 DB3 2014-10-26 23.36.17 Full.bak    
    26/10/2014  23:48     3,505,426,944 DB4 2014-10-26 23.36.59 Full.bak    
    27/10/2014  00:03     4,322,182,144 DB5 2014-10-26 23.48.12 Full.bak    
    ***27/10/2014  00:25     7,266,648,576 DB6 2014-10-27 00.04.13 Full.bak    
    27/10/2014  03:31    67,190,649,344 DB7 2014-10-27 00.25.51 Full.bak***
    27/10/2014  03:32       270,017,024 DB8 2014-10-27 03.31.19 Full.bak
```

There are some replication job runs at around 2 O'clock. I thought that may be the problem and I changed the time for my differential backup job a bit early so that it finishes before the replication job starts.
But the result is same . Job is successful. but most of the backups did not get updated and this time the last backup was taken at 19:36 and after that no backup at all.

Its really critical,Can someone please help me with what can be the reason for this ?
Your help is much appreciated.

I am using SQL server 2012

Thanks

Comment: Anything in the SQL Server or windows event log at this time?

Comment: I would start by checking backup history.  For instance: `SELECT * 
FROM msdb.dbo.backupset s 
WHERE s.database_name = 'DB6' 
AND s.type = 'D' 
ORDER BY s.backup_finish_date DESC`

Comment: I checked that first. That's how I came to know that some backups are missing.

Comment: Ah, Ok.  I thought you were just checking SQL Agent Job history.

Comment: There could be scenario that job is successful but the backups are not taking place. Did you check the job agent history? Do you have an option to 'Quit the job reporting success' in advanced tab?

Comment: Yes I do have that under 'On Success action'.but I assume it shd be the case only if all the backups are done and if some backup has problem, it should go to 'On Failure action'. am I missing something here ?